# How to get the verified status(Blue Tick) of the Facebook page Android

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to get the verified status (blue tick) for the facebook page using graph API in android

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString("fields", "name");
    GraphRequestAsyncTask graphRequestAsyncTask = new GraphRequest(
            AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),
            "/PageId/",
            null,
            HttpMethod.GET,
            new GraphRequest.Callback() {
                public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {
                    JSONObject jsonObject = response.getJSONObject();                       
                }
            }
    ).executeAsync();
```

What are the **fields** used to get the status

Comment: RTFM. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page#Reading

Comment: I already read the document. I hope the same with you. Can you please tell required the 'field' to get the verified status(Blue tick)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried using "is_verified" tag ?